# javascript string.lastIndexOf does not work with span innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

look the below example.

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<span id="spTest">Your current operation: Modify &raquo; newone</span>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sp = document.getElementById("spTest");
var str = sp.innerHTML;
//var str = "Your current operation: Modify &raquo; newone";
alert(str)
var index = str.lastIndexOf("&raquo;");
alert(index);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the above example will popup the "index" value -1. If I uncomment the line ""Your current operation: Modify » newone";", the result will be 30.

So I think the reason is because I use the "innerHTML" to get the text. What else can i use the get text inside span and get the right index result?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it has nothing to do with `innerHTML`. In the call to `lastIndexOf`, the `&raquo;` entity is not expanded as it is in the HTML code; instead it is considered as a raw string. Replace it with the actual character and it will work:

```
var index = str.lastIndexOf("»");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use innerHTML, you have to use `"»"` instead of `"&raquo;"`.